# C# base class of unbound generic type not usable?

Tags: c#, generics

I am stumped by weird behavior while working with generics in C#. Consider this code:

```
class CEmployee<T> { }
class CManager<T> : CEmployee<T> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CManager<String> cemp = new CManager<String>();
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().BaseType);
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().BaseType.FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(1);
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition());
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().BaseType);
        Console.WriteLine(cemp.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().BaseType.FullName); // Problem 1
        Console.WriteLine(2);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CManager<>));
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CManager<>).FullName);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CManager<>).BaseType);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CManager<>).BaseType.FullName); // Problem 1
        Console.WriteLine(3);
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CManager<>).Equals(cemp.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition()));
        Console.WriteLine(typeof(CEmployee<>).Equals(cemp.GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition().BaseType)); // Problem 2


    }
}
```

The output is

```
ConsoleApplication1.CManager`1[System.String]
ConsoleApplication1.CManager`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutr
ConsoleApplication1.CEmployee`1[System.String]
ConsoleApplication1.CEmployee`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neut
1
ConsoleApplication1.CManager`1[T]
ConsoleApplication1.CManager`1
ConsoleApplication1.CEmployee`1[T]

2
ConsoleApplication1.CManager`1[T]
ConsoleApplication1.CManager`1
ConsoleApplication1.CEmployee`1[T]

3
True
False
```

I am stumped as to why the base class of the unbound generic type is not fully usable:

1. Why am I getting nothing when I get the full name of the base
   type of unbound generic type? ("problem 1" in the code above)
2. Why if the base type of my CManager instance is
   CEmployee, and the type of the base class of the unbound
   type CManager<> is CEmployee<>, and the unbound type CManager
   "Equals" the generic type definition of my instance, the base type
   of the unbound type does not "Equals" the base type of the generic
   type definition of my instance?? ("problem 2" in the code above)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In reverse order:

2: because the base type is `CEmployee<T>`, not `CEmployee<>`. There is a difference; `CEmployee<>` is the type-definition; `CEmployee<T>` is bound to the `T` from the parent type. You can see this by looking at `IsGenericTypeDefinition` and `GetGenericArguments()[0]`

1: because the `FullName` of this form of generic type is not defined. This is [fully documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.type.fullname.aspx):

> If the current type contains generic type parameters that have not been replaced by specific types (that is, the ContainsGenericParameters property returns true), but the type is not a generic type definition (that is, the IsGenericTypeDefinition property returns false), this property returns null.

which is exactly what we discussed in "2".

Comment: Indeed! Which explains why if for #2 you put GetGenericTypeDefinition after BaseType, it did work.